# html mail not send

Tags: emails

I want sent email with Html tags, I install [mailsystem](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) and [htmlmail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) modules,
according to some tutorial that I read I provide `tpl` .

anyway
The main problem is when I select `HTMLMailSysytem` in `Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class` no email sending, but when I put it in `DefaultMailSystem` mail sent,
I try to find out why this happened in my custom module I try

```
$result = drupal_mail('cdigitdev', 'message_key', $to, user_preferred_language($user), array('body' => $body, 'subject' => $subject, 'headers' => array('Cc' => $header_cc, 'Bcc' => $header_bcc,'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed'), $from, TRUE));
  ym($result);
```

The result is

[image]
But I didn't receive any email !!!!

I think this is related to mail server that when I try to send html server drupal(php) tell it is sended but I did not receive any thing , is it right?

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I won't get in to, you should use an SMTP module and route your emails through a real email account. Check the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module. Details from project page:

> This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send email directly to an SMTP server. The module supports SMTP authentication and can even connect to servers using SSL if supported by PHP.

Otherwise your emails can (and will) get blocked as spam.

Comment: Actually it might be useful to get into some reasons. Most common is graylisting as far as my experience goes.

Comment: They did not send, I check spam folder even

Comment: @zhilevan  upload a PHP file that you make yourself.   Use only the mail() function from PHP.   See if you get an email that way.